# how to format a large txt file to bed

Tags: awk, bioinformatics, bed

I am trying to format CpG methylation calls from R package "methyKit" to simple bed format. Since it is a large file, i can not do it in Excel. I also tried Seqmonk, but it does not allow me to export the data in the format I want. Linux Awk/`sed` might be a good option, but I am new to them as well. Basically, I need to trim "chr" column, add "stop" column, convert "F" to "+" /"R" to "-", and freqC with 2 decimal places. Can you please help?

From:

```
chrBase chr base    strand  coverage  freqC   freqT
chr1.339    chr1    339 F   7      0.00   100.00
chr1.183    chr1    183 R   4      0.00   100.00
chr1.192    chr1    192 R   6      0.00   100.00
chr1.340    chr1    340 R   5      40.00  60.00
chr1.10007  chr1    10007   F   13     53.85  46.15
chr1.10317  chr1    10317   F   8      0.00   100.00
chr1.10346  chr1    10346   F   9      88.89  11.11
chr1.10349  chr1    10349   F   9      88.89  11.11
```

To:

```
   chr     start         stop      freqc  Coverage strand
    1   67678   67679   0   3   -
    1   67701   67702   0   3   -
    1   67724   67725   0   3   -
    1   67746   67747   0   3   -
    1   67768   67769   0.333333    3   -
    1   159446  159447  0   3   +
    1   162652  162653  0   3   +
    1   167767  167768  0.666667    3   +
    1   167789  167790  0.666667    3   +
    1   167797  167798  0   3   +
```

Comment: We generally expect you to show some research or coding effort. But at the very minimum, can you please [edit] to explain in more detail how the input maps to the desired output? Most people who know Awk don't know anything about bioinformatics.

Comment: There is no way you can get the start stop positions in the desired output from the input alone. Coverage numbers also changed.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you actually want, producing a BED6 file with the methylation percentage in the score column:

```
$ cat foo.awk
BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
{if(NR>1) {
    if($4=="F") {
        strand="+"
    } else {
        strand="-"
    }
    chromUse=gsub("chr", "", $2);
    print chromUse,$3-1,$3,$1,$6,strand,$5
}}
```

That would then be run with:

```
awk -f foo.awk input.txt > output.bed
```

The additional column 7 is the coverage, since genome viewers will only display a single score column:

```
1       338     339     chr1.339        0.00    +       7
1       182     183     chr1.183        0.00    -       4
1       191     192     chr1.192        0.00    -       6
1       339     340     chr1.340        40.00   -       5
1       10006   10007   chr1.10007      53.85   +       13
1       10316   10317   chr1.10317      0.00    +       8
1       10345   10346   chr1.10346      88.89   +       9
1       10348   10349   chr1.10349      88.89   +       9
```

You can tweak that further as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear the exact sequence you want since your `"From"` data does not correspond to what you show as your `"To"` results, but if what you are showing is the general format change and in the `"From"` data, you want to:

- discard field 1,
- retrieve the `"chr"` value from the end of field 2,
- if the 4th field is `"F"` make it `"+"` else if it is `"R"` make it `"-"` otherwise leave it unchanged,
- use the 3rd field as `"start"` and 3rd + 1 as `"stop"` (adjust whether to add or subtract `1` as needed to get the desired `"start"` and `"stop"` values),
- print 6th field as `"freqc"`,
- output 5th field as `"Coverage"`, and finally
- output modified 4th field as `"strand"`

If that is your goal, then with your from data in the file named `from`, you can do something like the following:

```bash
awk '
  BEGIN { OFS="\t"; print "chr","start","stop","freqc","Coverage","strand" } 
  FNR > 1 { 
    match($2, /[[:digit:]]+$/, arr)
    if ($4 == "F")
      $4 = "+"
    else if ($4 == "R")
      $4 = "-"
    print arr[0], $3, $3 + 1, $6, $5, $4
  }
' from
```

Explanation, the `BEGIN` rule is run before `awk` starts processing records (lines) from the file. Above it simply sets the Output Field Separator to `tab` and prints the heading.

The condition (pattern) of `FNR > 1` on the second rule processes the from file from the 2nd record (line) on (skipping the heading row). `FNR` is awk's way of saying File Record Number (even though it looks like the `N` and `R` are backwards).

`match($2, /[[:digit:]]+$/, arr)` splits the trailing digits from the second field into the first element of `arr` (e.g. `arr[0]`) and *not relevant here* sets the `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` internal variables telling you which character the first digit starts on and how many digits there are.

The `if` and `else if` statement does the `"F"` to `"+"` and `"R"` to `"-"` change. And, finally, the `print` statement just prints the modified values and unchanged fields in the order specified above.

**Example Output**

Running the above on your original `"From"` data will produce:

```
chr     start   stop    freqc   Coverage        strand
1       339     340     0.00    7       +
1       183     184     0.00    4       -
1       192     193     0.00    6       -
1       340     341     40.00   5       -
1       10007   10008   53.85   13      +
1       10317   10318   0.00    8       +
1       10346   10347   88.89   9       +
1       10349   10350   88.89   9       +
```

Let me know if this is close to what you explained in your question, and if not, drop a comment below.

The [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) is a great gawk/awk reference.